# ActiveRecord belongs_to association returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Spree::Quotation` as follows

```
class Spree::Quotation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :payment_term, -> { where(service_type: 'Spree::Quotation') },
          class_name: 'PaymentTerm',
          foreign_key: 'service_id'
end
```

This is the `PaymentTerm` model

```
class PaymentTerm < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :quotation, -> { where(service_type: 'Spree::Quotation') },
             class_name: 'Spree::Quotation',
             primary_key: 'service_id'
end
```

this is the contents of `payment_terms` table

```
development=# SELECT "payment_terms".* FROM "payment_terms";

 id | service_id |   service_type   |     term     | 
----+------------+------------------+--------------+
  1 |          1 | Spree::Quotation | 100% upfront |
(1 row)
```

now when I do `Spree::Quotation.first.payment_term` I am getting the payment_term correctly

```
2.1.8 :007 > Spree::Quotation.first.payment_term
  Spree::Quotation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "spree_quotations".* FROM "spree_quotations" ORDER BY "spree_quotations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  PaymentTerm Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "payment_terms".* FROM "payment_terms" WHERE "payment_terms"."service_id" = $1 AND "payment_terms"."service_type" = 'Spree::Quotation' LIMIT 1  [["service_id", 1]]
 => #<PaymentTerm id: 1, service_id: 1, service_type: "Spree::Quotation", term: "100% upfront",... >
```

But when I do `PaymentTerm.first.quotation`, I am getting `nil`

```
2.1.8 :008 > PaymentTerm.first.quotation
  PaymentTerm Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "payment_terms".* FROM "payment_terms" ORDER BY "payment_terms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Why is it not loading the quotation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to specify condition in `belongs_to` association as `payment_terms` table has attribute `service_id`.

```
class PaymentTerm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quotation, class_name: 'Spree::Quotation', foreign_key: 'service_id'
end
```